# Need help in dealing with workplace harassment

Tags: work-environment, human-resources, india, harassment

I went through so much workplace harassment in the last year and due to this I am now suffering from poor mental and physical health

It is really unfair if all team is working from home and your manager is asking the fresher to work from the client's office. And I am working from the office since last 5 months. When I asked them to allow me as well for WFH then he used to say that they are also coming to the office in March or April but that didn't happen.

I wrote an email to report HR about my health condition and also a valid reason that I will not be able to work in the location provided as the weather is not suitable and I become sick every now and then because I need to travel to my home every weekend then they I also much cared about the employees well being and instead gave me warning if I don't come to the office then we will cut it from my leaves even if you WFH.
And the same thing happened last week when I already informed my manager that I am extremely ill due to the viral flu and very poor condition so I have to travel to my home town to get proper treatment and care.
I continued to WFH even though I was sick. And it's really shocking my manager sent an email to HR to cut off my leaves as she is not present in the office. This is really unfair when everybody else gets other privileges in the team than me but company policy says differently.
that We provide equal opportunities to all our employees and to all eligible applicants for employment in our company.

All this mental harassment started when I joined this project, and the manager started treating me wrongly. Initially, I thought he is trying to make me comfortable in the project but it was not the case.

1. One day I was having extreme pain due to Menstrual cramps so I decided to take a sick leave so I contacted my manager to inform the same. I told him I am having strong stomach pain and I need leave. He started asking me what kind o I am having that pain. I finally told him that I am having pain due to my periods. What he next asked were really awkward situations for any Woman. He asked me does that pain happen every time. Do you have irregular periods? Totally unnecessary and uncomfortable questions. It is a shameful situation that no gents in my family have the liberty to speak with a Woman and this outsider can directly be pointing or openly asked about.
2. He used to try to message me on the personal whats app number and used to comment on my what's app display pictures often which is not the usual thing for a manager about how beautiful it is etc
3. One more incident he tried to insult me. I was asked to give a KT session about one of the module to all other colleagues. Initially, I get training about the same module from my manager and I referred to its recording notes to prepare myself for before the session. When I completed the session he took one internal meeting and told me that everything is incorrect. I understand it is right to correct team members when needed, but its not right to insult me and make fun in front of other colleagues.
   I really believe my company has an employee well-being-oriented work ethic and has zero-tolerance against Workplace harassment including physical, verbal, sexual, and emotional harassment. I believe right justice will be provided to me in this matter. I am ready to provide all pieces of evidence against this matter which I have.

Can someone help me with how should take this matter ahead? Or what email I should send to the higher HR department?

It is quite unlikely that you will experience an event like this in the beginning of your profession that will shake you to the core and leave you with painful memories for the rest of your life.

Comment: You seem to *negotiate* your sickness. Sickness is not controlable by you and therefor not negotiable, either you are too sick to work, or you are not. Where in the world are you? Are there no laws, at what time or under which conditions you count as "out sick with no penalties"?

Comment: @jwh20 you think a male manager asking about the menstruation cycle of women is the right thing? And supporting he has done nothing wrong?

Comment: @jwh20 I don't know about your locale, but in Indian organizations, point #1 and #2 are considered harassment for sure.

Comment: Given the term "fresher", I presume this is in India.

Comment: No, I think there is way more to what's going on here than what's been stated.

Comment: @jwh20 that is a different thing. While I do not disagree that we're seeing (reading) the tip of the iceberg, but as stated , #1 and #2 are something unusual at best.

Comment: Well someone took offence at the directness of my previous comment, so I'll try to rephrase it. You need to be more honest with yourself when you make a statement like "I have to travel to my home town to get proper treatment and care". If you're looking for ways to be allowed to work from home, then you need *valid* reasons and, unless you have a particularly rare medical condition, *that's not one of them*. I'm explicitly *not* addressing any other points in the question here, but only advising that you don't "muddy the waters" with irrelevant and invalid excuses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone help me with how should take this matter ahead?

1. Take a deep breath, collect yourself, stand in front of the mirror and tell yourself "I will take control of the situation, I will help myself". Don't despair, you CAN make this a lot better.
2. Start doing your homework: read up on corporate policies (employee handbook) and local labor laws. If you are in a union, reach out to your union rep. If there is a "citizen advice" office or equivalent, ask for advice.
3. Document, document, document: Start saving emails, zoom chats, transcripts of verbal interaction. Make sure every record includes formal detail: date, time, people involved, context, etc. If something particular egregious occurs, consider having the record notarized (there are online services for this now).
4. Talk to your doctor. Make sure you get properly diagnosed and that any workplace accommodations you may need are documented. Also ask about the "normal" process for sick days
5. So you need to understand your rights, definition of discrimination and protected classes, and assess to what extent your employer violates the current rules. These rules vary GREATLY from country to country, state to state and company to company. Without more details, we can't help here.
6. In many jurisdictions your employers behavior would be outright illegal.

Once you have all the information on the table, you can plan your next step. Start with defining your goal. What exactly is it that you want and how you define success? Could be "formal permit to WFH forever plus all leave time reinstated", "move to a different manager", "leave employer with a big fat severance package". etc. Once you have a goal you can plan the individual steps and negotiation tactics to get you there. Again, consulting an external expert can help here. Negotiations can be tricky if it's your first time around.

> Or what email I should send to the higher HR department?

HR's main role is to ensure compliance and prevent the company from getting sued. It's not their job to make the employees happy or solve their personal problems. Chances are approaching HR will be the first step, but not to ask for help but to make them nervous and afraid. A sentence like "On Dec 12th I called in in sick because of stomach pain. My manager asked what type of stomach cramps I had. My lawyer thought that was an odd thing to do, can you please explain to me our company policy about medical privacy and data protection?" After 3 or 4 of these, HR will be VERY nervous and much more willing to give you what you want.

> It is quite unlikely that you will experience an event like this in the beginning of your profession that will shake you to the core and leave you with painful memories for the rest of your life.

Yes and no. Almost everyone will experience some confrontation with their employer during their career and dealing with this is something that most people have to learn.

The hard lesson: there is no fairy god mother that will swing her magic wand and solve the problem for you. The key is to not be a victim but to actively take charge of the situation. Having to go through this during your first job is not great, but once you've dealt with it, you are prepared for all future problems to come.

Comment: Sorry about this. Apparently the HIPAA training I received was either wrong or that training I got wasn't HIPAA. I'll remove the reference.

Comment: I really like your answer and the most important part the hard lesson you taught which is reality. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to WFH, what is stated in your contract? It is not uncommon for companies to demand to work from offices when they are newly employed as I interpret "fresher" meaning. And it sounds as this is only temporary for 5 months and then you would be free to WFH. So regarding WFH I would say go for this 5 months as said and then you will have the WFH benefit.

Comment: Sorry maybe I have not written it correctly, SO I am the only person who is working from the office since last 5 months when all the other colleagues didn't show up on any day and continued WFH.

Comment: "I have not written it correctly, SO I am the only person who is working from the office since last 5 months when all the other colleagues didn't show up on any day and continued WFH." - You being unable to WFH isn't a form of harassment.  You being new to the company is a valid reason to prevent you from WFH

Answer (score 0):

**1:** He is looking at it from a pure management perspective, so he knows that an employee will regularly be missing and he can plan accordingly.  Not tactful of him, but maybe he just isn't a tactful guy when it comes to such things.

**2:** he might just trying to be nice, but yea he is way out of bounds here.

**3:** Again probably no malicious intent, but he should have discussed any errors one on one and not in front of the team.

Taking all of this in account, he might be a bit dim, have u tried talking to him about this directly? People often don't see themselves what they are doing wrong, and are able to change if spoken to in a direct manner. Because going to HR straight away might cause long term conflict with him (if he manages to stay on after) or colleagues who are friends with him. So if you can resolve it peacefully with him it would be better than to get him in trouble and risk retaliation, and if he doesn't change after your conversation you can at least show that u handled the situation in good will.

Comment: Yes, I made several attempts to speak with him but to no avail. And I believe that it is wrong to remain silent about these issues since doing so will eventually cause him to victimize additional women in the workplace.

Comment: @Tinks_say if it has been personally discussed and he did not respond, go to HR on person (often works better than mail) and discuss it.